# POST request with WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to submit some very simple information the user inputs and have the info stored in $. I am writing a WordPress which I am total noob at so here is my code so far:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php dt_storage('have_sidebar', true); ?>
<?php get_template_part('top-bg'); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <?php get_template_part('nav'); ?>
        <div id="container">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Кожен тест на Др. Дерм</strong></h1>
            <div class="about" style="visibility: visible; margin-bottom: 25px;"><div class="about-cont"><div class="about-iiner" style="max-width: 735px;"><em>Преди да направите теста, дегримирайте и измийте лицето си /или след баня/, подсушете добре със салфетка и без да поставяте козметичен или друг продукт на кожата си, изчакайте 30 минути.
                            След като изтече това време, огледайте добре кожата си на силна светлина.
                            За да определим продуктите, от които се нуждае Вашата кожа, моля, отговорете на следните въпроси:
                        </em></div></div></div>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['drder'])){
                echo "1";
            }
?>
            <form action="" method="post" name="drder">
            <div style="padding-top: 0;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>1. Обшо състояние на кожата. Как усещате Вашата кожа?</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="1" name="q1"> Свежа, мека, хидратирана.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="2" name="q1"> Суха, с чувство за опъване след почистване.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="3" name="q1"> Омазняваща се с широки пори и лъщене в следобедните часове.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="4" name="q1"> Раздразнена, възпалена, некомфортна. Понякога усещате щипане и парене със зачервявания.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="5" name="q1"> Омазняваща се, груба, замърсена, с широки пори и с акне.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="6" name="q1"> Уморена с фини повърхностни линии и/или люспички. Девитализирана и отпусната с видими бръчки.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>2. Как преценяте порите на кожата на лицето си?</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="1" name="q2"> Фини и чисти.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="2" name="q2"> Големи в Т-зоната, фини по скулите.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="3" name="q2"> Големи и замърсени.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>3. Как определяте структурата и еластичността на Вашата кожа?</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="1" name="q3"> Стегната и еластична.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="2" name="q3"> Мазна с лъщене, но еластична.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="3" name="q3"> Тънка с мимически бръчки.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="4" name="q3"> Със загуба на еластичност и с бръчки.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>4. Как определяте тена на Вашето лице?</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="1" name="q4"> Равен.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="2" name="q4"> Неравен със зачервявания.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="3" name="q4"> Блед, мътен, без виталност.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="4" name="q4"> С видими капиляри и зачервявания.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="5" name="q4"> С възрастова или слънчева пигментация.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="6" name="q4"> Уморена с фини повърхностни линии и/или люспички. Девитализирана и отпусната с видими бръчки.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>5. Моля, посочете Вашата възраст:</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="M" name="q5"> Под 20 години.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="S" name="q5"> Между 20 – 30 години.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="B" name="q5"> Между 30 – 40 години.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="R" name="q5"> Между 40 – 50 години.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="D" name="q5"> Над 50 години.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 15px; width: 100%;">
            <div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class="but-wrap"><input name="drder" type="submit" class="button go_submit" value="ЗАВЪРШВАНЕ НА ТЕСТА"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see my task is very simple - I have a form titled "drder" and a submit button titled "drder" too. But when I try to see if $_POST['drder'] is set by the user I get no information whatsoever. I also tried var_dumping the $_POST and I got an array:0 result. I have no idea why I can not use post requests with WordPress.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, I changed the order of checking isset drder.

```html
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['drder'])){
                echo "1";
            }
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php dt_storage('have_sidebar', true); ?>
<?php get_template_part('top-bg'); ?>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <?php get_template_part('nav'); ?>
        <div id="container">
            <h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>Кожен тест на Др. Дерм</strong></h1>
            <div class="about" style="visibility: visible; margin-bottom: 25px;"><div class="about-cont"><div class="about-iiner" style="max-width: 735px;"><em>Преди да направите теста, дегримирайте и измийте лицето си /или след баня/, подсушете добре със салфетка и без да поставяте козметичен или друг продукт на кожата си, изчакайте 30 минути.
                            След като изтече това време, огледайте добре кожата си на силна светлина.
                            За да определим продуктите, от които се нуждае Вашата кожа, моля, отговорете на следните въпроси:
                        </em></div></div></div>
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['drder'])){
                echo "1";
            }
?>
            <form action="" method="post">
            <div style="padding-top: 0;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>1. Обшо състояние на кожата. Как усещате Вашата кожа?</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="1" name="q1"> Свежа, мека, хидратирана.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="2" name="q1"> Суха, с чувство за опъване след почистване.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="3" name="q1"> Омазняваща се с широки пори и лъщене в следобедните часове.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="4" name="q1"> Раздразнена, възпалена, некомфортна. Понякога усещате щипане и парене със зачервявания.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="5" name="q1"> Омазняваща се, груба, замърсена, с широки пори и с акне.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="6" name="q1"> Уморена с фини повърхностни линии и/или люспички. Девитализирана и отпусната с видими бръчки.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>2. Как преценяте порите на кожата на лицето си?</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="1" name="q2"> Фини и чисти.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="2" name="q2"> Големи в Т-зоната, фини по скулите.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="3" name="q2"> Големи и замърсени.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>3. Как определяте структурата и еластичността на Вашата кожа?</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="1" name="q3"> Стегната и еластична.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="2" name="q3"> Мазна с лъщене, но еластична.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="3" name="q3"> Тънка с мимически бръчки.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="4" name="q3"> Със загуба на еластичност и с бръчки.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>4. Как определяте тена на Вашето лице?</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="1" name="q4"> Равен.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="2" name="q4"> Неравен със зачервявания.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="3" name="q4"> Блед, мътен, без виталност.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="4" name="q4"> С видими капиляри и зачервявания.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="5" name="q4"> С възрастова или слънчева пигментация.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="6" name="q4"> Уморена с фини повърхностни линии и/или люспички. Девитализирана и отпусната с видими бръчки.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <h2 style="padding-bottom: 1px !important;"><strong>5. Моля, посочете Вашата възраст:</strong></h2>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="M" name="q5"> Под 20 години.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="S" name="q5"> Между 20 – 30 години.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="B" name="q5"> Между 30 – 40 години.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="R" name="q5"> Между 40 – 50 години.</div>
                <div style="padding-bottom: 5px;"><input type="radio" value="D" name="q5"> Над 50 години.</div>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <div style="padding-top: 15px; width: 100%;">
            <div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;">
                <div class="but-wrap"><input name="drder" type="submit" class="button go_submit" value="ЗАВЪРШВАНЕ НА ТЕСТА"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        
    </div>
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Didn't work. Also no info for $_POST in the var_dump function.

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't display anything as a result of clicking the submit button.